# interpolate string with variable name in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to interpolate value inside interpolate?

I am using a file where I have written message string and using `{{ vm.variable }}`  but I am unable to display the string with variable value on HTML.

*input string* ( in JS ): `"Welcome {{name}} to the World."`

*desired output string* (in HTML ): `"Welcome John Smith to the world."`

look my code below

```js
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', [])
        .value('_MSG_', {
                "signup": "Welcome {{name}} to the World.",
                "login": "last login from {{location}}"
        }).controller('MessageController', function($scope, $parse, $interpolate, _MSG_){
            var vm = this;
            vm.name = "John Smith";
            vm.location = "India";
            vm.welcomeMessage = _MSG_.signup;
            //========trial 1 =======
            // vm.finalString = $interpolate(vm.welcomeMessage); 
            // nothing happens but
            //=====trial 2=====
            // set {{vm.name}} in _MSG_.signup and do below
            // vm.finalString = $parse(_MSG_).assign($scope, vm.name);
            // ERROR [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 9 of the expression [Weclome {{vm.name}}.] starting at [{{vm.name}}.].
        });
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<head> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MessageController as vm ">
    {{ vm.welcomeMessage }} ==> Welcome John Smith to the world


    // trial 1

    {{ vm.finalString }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I forgot to add some code into HTML to make in angular compatible but do not know how to edit the code part while editing the question.

Comment: Question is not clear. Needs more explanation. What are you expecting?

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: sorry for that. I need the complete string ; see in HTML part in code after  ==>

Comment: @lin yes, mentioned in the commented lines, within code

Comment: Just remove pipe symbol to avoid the error `{{ vm.welcomeMessage | }}` to `{{ vm.welcomeMessage }}`

Comment: oops, that was typo.  @Mr_Perfect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind `$interpolate` to `this\vm`

Like: `$interpolate(vm.welcomeMessage)(this);`

DEMO:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .value('MSG', {
    "signup": "Welcome {{name}} to the World.",
    "login": "last login from {{location}}"
  }).controller('MessageController', function($scope, $parse, $interpolate, MSG) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.name = "John Smith";
    vm.location = "India";
    vm.welcomeMessage = MSG.signup;
    vm.finalString = $interpolate(vm.welcomeMessage)(this);
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<head> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MessageController as vm ">
    {{ vm.welcomeMessage }} ==> Welcome John Smith
    
    <br>// trial 1<br>
    {{ vm.finalString }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not printing the variable name even i tried `vm` an `this` both as second parameter

Comment: oh, it's my mistake, I need to remove `vm.` from MSG string value too. Thanks

Comment: @pro.mean: glad to help you.:)